# How to go back to previous or autoscale in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to go back to previous range or to autoscale after setting xrange or yrange? 
I don't see any change in range using `set autoscale xy` or `set autoscale`. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirements? Those commands should work fine to set autoscaling. In the interactive wxt terminal there are buttons to go to the previous range. Or, after a plot, you can save the current range using e.g. the `GPVAL_X_MIN` and `GPVAL_X_MAX` variables. Or you can use the `save` command etc. You see, there are several ways. Which one you need depends on the details.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
set xrange [*:*]
set yrange [*:*]
```

that will reset gnuplot to autoscaling.

Comment: Thats the same as using `set autoscale xy`, which the OP uses.

Comment: I used `set xrange [*:*]` as well followed by `replot`, nothing updated. So reinstalled the copy and since then it is working just fine. Thank you all!